# How can I get the current state of another android application as a bitmap?

Tags: bitmap, application-state

Is it possible on android to get a Bitmap object (regular size, not a thumbnail) which represents the current state of another application running in the background, or a Bitmap object which represents the current state of an activity in the background of which we know the componentName?